# django admin search with multiple words

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have troubles using the `search_fields` when the search expression has multiple words and i want to perform a *startswith* search

I have a class

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  kw = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
  ...

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  search_fields = ('^kw',)
```

The `'^'` indicates that i want to perform a startswith search. If i'm looking for the kw 'foo fuu', django will perform the query:

```
select * from app_foo where `foo`.`kw` like 'foo%' and `foo`.`kw` like 'fuu%'
```

This query obviously gives zero results. What should i do to make the engine looking for `'foo fuu%'` ?

Comment: It seems Django splits the query on spaces so this may not be possible to do. Have you considered the full-text option with `@`?

Comment: Is this possible to change the splitting token ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The docs say: `Note that the query input is split by spaces, so, following this example, it's currently not possible to search for all records in which first_name is exactly 'john winston' (containing a space).`

Comment: take a look at the file django/contrib/admin/views/main.py (django 1.4), line 362: for bit in self.query.split(). I dont think you can change spliting token officially, unless hacking into that file

Comment: Maybe you should file a bug.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about override `self.query` so `split()` doesn't work?

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList


class UnsplitableUnicode(str):
    "An object that behaves like a unicode string but cannot be split()"
    def split(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return [self]

class MultiWordSearchChangeList(ChangeList):
    "Changelist that allows searches to contain spaces"
    def get_query_set(self, request):
        self.query = UnsplitableUnicode(self.query)
        return super(MultiWordSearchChangeList, self).get_query_set(request)

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return MultiWordSearchChangeList
```

Comment: This solution seemed elegant but i can't make it work. Have you tried it? I can't enter in the overrided split method and i can't understand why

Comment: Thanks, updated. I should be slapped for posting code on SO without testing it first... it didn't work in `__init__` because `ChangeList.__init__` both sets `self.query` *and* uses it. Overriding it in `get_query_set()` allows us to catch `self.query` before it's used.

Comment: @Valachio you might want to use `str` in Python 3 instead.

Comment: Elegant solution indeed, but for some reason it doesn't work in Django 2.2.9. If you perform a prefix search with `^field`, it looks like `split()` method is not called on `self.query` variable of the `ChangeList` instance.

I have slightly modified your solution; I will post my solution as a separate one because there are not enough characters in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Thai Tran it's a bit messy. Here is the section you would have to edit.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList

class CustomChangeList(ChangeList):
    def get_query_set(self, request):
        #Basically copy and paste in entire function and edit the piece copied in here.

        if self.search_fields and self.query:
            orm_lookups = [construct_search(str(search_field))
                           for search_field in self.search_fields]
            for bit in self.query.split():
                or_queries = [models.Q(**{orm_lookup: bit})
                              for orm_lookup in orm_lookups]
                qs = qs.filter(reduce(operator.or_, or_queries))
            if not use_distinct:
                for search_spec in orm_lookups:
                    if lookup_needs_distinct(self.lookup_opts, search_spec):
                        use_distinct = True
                        break


class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return CustomChangeList
```

Speaking from experience, overriding ChangeList has caused problems down the road.

Comment: So far, it's the least bad solution but i'm afraid of compatibility after a release of a new Django's version. But thanks

Comment: Yes. We overrode a ChangeList for some reason last year and when 1.4 came out we had to rip it out...lesson learned. If we were forced to do it again I'd clearly document it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet link that can make advanced search for admin:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2322/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified version of [Mike Fogel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14490862/170159), which does not seem to work in recent Django versions:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList


class UnsplittableStr(str):
    "An object that behaves like a unicode string but cannot be split()"
    def split(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return [self]


class MultiWordSearchMixin:
    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        query = request.GET.get('q', '')
        request.GET = request.GET.copy()
        request.GET['q'] = UnsplittableStr(query)
        return ChangeList
```

Now you can inherit from the mixin in your `ModelAdmin` class:

```py
class FooAdmin(MultiWordSearchMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Your ModelAdmin code here"""
```