# Django multiple dbs - admin search results using a read-only db

Tags: django, django-admin, django-settings, django-database

I'm using the admin [`search_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields) functionality.

The problem: some of my tables are very big. So search is taking forever, and adding extra load on my production database.

As I'm having a follower of my production db, I though a good idea would be to use the follower as a read-only db, especially for those kind of requests.

So I decided to add a 'read-only' db in `settings.DATABASES` and surcharge `ModelAdmin.get_search_results` in my admin classes:

```
def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
    queryset, use_distinct = super(ReadOnlyDatabaseAdmin, self)\
        .get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)

    queryset = queryset.using('read-only')

    return queryset, use_distinct
```

After this update, I started to get some router errors when trying to set some object as foreign key related object of another object:

```
Cannot assign "...": the current database router prevents this relation
```

**NB: the read-only database was the same as the default one when I tested and got the aforementioned error**, I didn't use the follower yet. I just have set a `'read-only'` key in `settings.DATABASES`, pointing to the same dict as `DATABASES['default']`.

So the problem is not coming from using a different database, but strictly from the database router.

To give more detail: this error is notably coming from admin actions that are performed when in a admin-search-results page (`/admin/app/obj/?q=...`).

I figured it's maybe because I replace the `queryset` object in the method. Maybe this object is actually re-used somewhere else notably in admin actions...? I am currently looking into this.

So I'm interested in:

- finding the reason of the error
- and/or finding another way of performing admin search requests on a follower database to offload the main database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the answer to the error is to do instead:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    queryset = queryset.using('read-only')
```

Indeed, the search results are dont with a GET, while the admin actions are done with a POST.

I will have to check this

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly you are looking for [How to improved query performance in Django admin search on related fields (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669807/how-to-improved-query-performance-in-django-admin-search-on-related-fields-mysq), but it can help to optimize the queries.